# JSON RPC Parameters C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, rpc

I am trying to create a method to send JSONRPC 2.0 commands using newtonsoft. I want to be able to pass parameters ant their values. Here is what I have so far

```
public void test(params object[] parameters)
{
    JObject joe = new JObject();
    joe.Add(new JProperty("jsonrpc", "2.0"));
    joe.Add(new JProperty("id", "1"));
    joe.Add(new JProperty("method", "Component.Set"));

    JArray props = new JArray();
    foreach (object parameter in parameters)
    {
        props.Add(parameter);
    }

    joe.Add(new JProperty("params", props));
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(joe);
}
```

But my problem is that it only sends the parameter names, I don't know how to pass the values for the paramters

So basically, I am getting this

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": "1",
  "method": "Component.Set",
  "params": [
    "Name",
    "GO"
  ]
}
```

when what I am looking for is something like this

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1234,
  "method": "Component.Set", 
  "params": {
    "Name": "My APM",
    "Controls": [
      {
        "Name": "ent.xfade.gain", 
        "Value": ‐100.0,
        "Ramp": 2.0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I generate JSON with this format?

Comment: What may `parameters` contain?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64286643/send-correct-json-as-parameter-to-rpc