# Send correct JSON as parameter to RPC

Tags: c#, json, rpc

I need to make an rpc to a thirh party API and send the following JSON

```
{
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "id":"number",
  "method":"login.user",
  "params":{
  "login":"string",
  "password":"string"
  }
}
```

I have created a method to make the rcp but i cannot get the correct JSON to be send

```
        public JObject Post()
    {
        object[] a_params = new object[] { "\"login\" : \"test@test.ru\"", "\"password\": \"Password\""};

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://test.test.ru/v2.0");

        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";

        JObject joe = new JObject();
        joe["jsonrpc"] = "2.0";
        joe["id"] = 1;
        joe["method"] = "login.user";

        if (a_params != null)
        {
            if (a_params.Length > 0)
            {
                JArray props = new JArray();
                foreach (var p in a_params)
                {
                    props.Add(p);
                }
                joe.Add(new JProperty("params", props));
            }
        }

        string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(joe);
        // serialize json for the request
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
        webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;


        WebResponse webResponse = null;
        try
        {
            using (webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream str = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(str))
                    {
                        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(sr.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException webex)
        {

            using (Stream str = webex.Response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(str))
                {
                    var tempRet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(sr.ReadToEnd());
                    return tempRet;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

With my code i'm getting the following JSON

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"method":"login.user","params":["\"login\" : \"v.ermachenkov@mangazeya.ru\"","\"password\": \"AmaYABzP2\""]}
```

As i understand my error is that params is an array([]) instead of an object({}). Based on my method how can get the correct json?

Answer (score 1):

I correct my mistake. The code shoukd be

```
JObject a_params = new JObject { new JProperty("login", "login"), new JProperty("password", "Password") };

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://test.test.ru/v2.0");

        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";

        JObject joe = new JObject();
        joe["jsonrpc"] = "2.0";
        joe["id"] = "1";
        joe["method"] = "login.user";
        joe.Add(new JProperty("params", a_params));
```